# Involutive distributions?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

How do we check exactly that a distribution is involutive?

I have the following definition in my book:
A $k-$dimensional distribution $\Delta$ on a manifold $M$ is a smooth choice of a k-dimensional subspace $\Delta_{p} \subseteq T_{p}M$. The distribution is called $involutive$ if $\left [ \Delta , \Delta \right ]\subseteq \Delta$.

In my case i have the following vector fields: for $x=(x,y,\theta ,\varphi )\in \Omega :=\mathbb{R}^{2}\times S^{1}\times(- \frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{4})$, let $X=\frac{\partial }{\partial \varphi  }$ and $Y=\cos\theta \frac{\partial }{\partial x}+\sin\theta \frac{\partial }{\partial y}+ \frac{\tan\varphi }{C}\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta }$, where $C$ is some constant. Find out if the distribution $\Delta = \langle X,Y \rangle$ is involutive or not.

Okay, i have computed the Lie bracket $\left [ X,Y \right ]=\frac{1}{C \cos ^{2}{\theta }}\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta }$, but i don't really know what to do now. Can anybody help me with this example, please? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The requirement that $[\Delta, \Delta] \subseteq \Delta$ can be determined by ensuring that all pairwise Lie Brackets of the vector fields that make up the distribution are themselves in the distribution.  See [Distributions (differential geometry)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28differential_geometry%29).  In your scenario there is only one bracket to consider so we ask, does there exist functions $a, b$ such that
$$[X, Y] = aX + bY$$
i.e.
$$\frac{1}{C \cos ^{2}{\theta }}\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta } = a\frac{\partial }{\partial \varphi  } + b\left(\cos\theta \frac{\partial }{\partial x}+\sin\theta \frac{\partial }{\partial y}+ \frac{\tan\varphi }{C}\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta }\right)$$

The answer is no since no linear combination of $X$ and $Y$ can produce the vector $\frac{d}{d\theta}$.

Comment: You might want to point out what $a$ and $b$ are.

Comment: @Lullaby - Happy to help.